# How to using library java web application

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets, restful-url

I'm trying to build a java web application base on a servlet, restful web service or something.  It will be a server, getting a request and returning a JSON object. But I'm having trouble using this library ( my web server needs it ). This library includes some folder, which has content data for the library.
[image]

I can use this library on a java application ( not web ) by copying all data folders into my java application's folder, and adding lib/jar into the project ( I'm using NetBeans IDE ). But in the web application it always has a problem when initialization it. ( VietTokenizer is the main processing class of this lib)

```
VietTokenizer vt = new VietTokenizer(); // error here !
```

So, how can I use this on a web application?

```
you can download this library in here:
```

http://mim.hus.vnu.edu.vn/phuonglh/tools/vn.hus.nlp.tokenizer-4.1.1-src.tar.gz

```
or here (two version)
```

http://vlsp.vietlp.org:8080/demo/?page=resources&tool=tokenizer

Comment: In a web application, add it to `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is right, but you can also add jar file to web container's lib folder, in case there are more applications referencing it

Comment: i tried, WEB-INF/lib doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE like netbeans or eclipse you can easily put them in the lib folder. So IDE will bundle all the libraries when you build the war file

Comment: can you try this lib. I already tried by many way but i can't do it